# No Crash when static member variables are deleted

Tags: c++, c++11

I have the below code:

```
#include <iostream>

class A
{
public:

static void* operator new(std::size_t sz) throw();
static void operator delete(void* ptr);
static A obja[2];
static int i;
void show()
{
std::cout << "Called Show" << std::endl;
}
A(const char * where)
{
std::cout << where << std::endl;
}
~A()
{
std::cout << "Called Destructor " <<  std::endl;
}
};

A A::obja[2] = {A("global1"),A("global2")};

int A::i = 0;

static void* A::operator new(std::size_t sz) throw()
{
std::cout << "Called new " <<  std::endl;
std::cout << "Addr of " << i <<  " " << &obja[i] << std::endl;
return &obja[i];    
}

static void A::operator delete(void* ptr)
{
std::cout << "Called delete " << ptr << std::endl;
}
int main()
{
A::i = 0;
A * a1 = new A("local main 1");
std::cout << "Addr of a1 " << a1 <<  std::endl;
a1->show();
delete a1;
A::i = 1;
A * a2 = new A("local main 2");
std::cout << "Addr of a2 " << a2 <<  std::endl;
a1->show();
delete a2;
}
```

I am purposefully deleting static variable as in code due to some reason - I was expecting that when the program would terminate the global / static variable destruction would happen and an segmentation fault should be observed (cause they are already de-allocated) - but the program terminated successfully:

```
$ c++ test3.cpp -std=c++11

$ ./a.exe
global1
global2
Called new
Addr of 0 0x408030
local main 1
Addr of a1 0x408030
Called Show
Called Destructor
Called delete 0x408030
Called new
Addr of 1 0x408031
local main 2
Addr of a2 0x408031
Called Show
Called Destructor
Called delete 0x408031
Called Destructor
Called Destructor
```

Should we not experience a segmentation fault here - is it legitimate?

Comment: Undefined behaviour can do anithing - it's undefined.

Comment: Why should it crash? You don't do anything illegal or invalid as far as I can see. You don't actually delete `obja[1]` itself, just the pointer to it returned by the `new` before, your `operator delete` function doesn't attempt to free or deallocate anything it shouldn't.

Comment: "segmentation fault" is not part of the C++ language (and as such never guaranteed to happen)

Comment: I believe the static objetcs obja[0] and obja[1] are getting deleted - I print the address of ptr in delete function - its the same as of obj's variable

Comment: Allocation `new` and deallocation `delete`, there is nothing wrong with deallocating what you allocated. Also, `std::cout << "Addr of a2 " << a1 <<  std::endl;` this is some interesting debugging

Comment: By doing `delete a2` you call your own `operator delete` function which does the actual deallocation. The object pointed to by `a2` (i.e. `obja[1]`) is *destructed* and should not be accessed or used again until constructed again, but it's not actually deallocated or free'd or deleted itself. In short, you do nothing wrong here.

Comment: Thanks for pointing out I modified the code - it was a typo mistake but however the address of object - both static and dynamic allocated ones where same

Comment: The compiler will call destruction of static data member variables and would fail as the memory is already de-allocated - that is what I am trying to state

Comment: At which point do you believe the program should crash?

Comment: When the program is exiting - Destructors (12.4) for initialized objects of static storage duration (declared at block scope or at namespace scope) are called as a result of returning from main and as a result of calling exit (18.3).  If an object is initialized statically, the object is destroyed in the same order as if the object was dynamically initialized. For an object of array or class type, all subobjects of that object are destroyed before any local object with static storage duration initialized during the construction of the sub- objects is destroyed.

Comment: Destructors normally don't deallocate any memory unless you call a memory deallocation function in the body. The destructor for your particular class does nothing at all with the object (it only prints a message). While it is undefined behaviour to destroy an object twice, in practice repeated calls to an empty destructor don't lead to crashes.

Comment: My side trying to resolve my project code issue - for example above I added a couple of data member variables in the class and manipulated in destructor - still no crash / issues observed

Comment: What kind of issue are you trying to resolve? Not crashing at undefined behaviour is not a resolvable issue.

Comment: Project code is crashing and If I was able to simulate via my example code then seek the fix for the issue

Comment: If your example program crashes, you've not necessarily reproduced the problem with your real project, you've just made an example program that crashes. You have to debug your real project.

Comment: But definitely double destruction is an issue here - though its not crashing here

Comment: It is easy to make it crash, just declare a non-static member of type e.g. std::string and init it with some long string. But what will it buy you?

Comment: Establishes that my expectation was correct even though when it was not crashing. Thanks I need to break the static bonding of objects. Any idea?